# Not able to join worker nodes using kubectl with updated aws-auth configmap

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm setting up AWS EKS cluster using terraform from an EC2 instance. Basically the setup includes EC2 launch configuration and autoscaling for worker nodes. After creating the cluster, I am able to configure kubectl with aws-iam-authenticator. When I did

```
kubectl get nodes
```

It returned

> No resources found

as the worker nodes were not joined. So I tried updating `aws-auth-cm.yaml` file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - rolearn: <ARN of instance role (not instance profile)>
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
      groups:
        - system:bootstrappers
        - system:nodes
```

with IAM role ARN of the worker node. And did

```
kubectl apply -f aws-auth-cm.yaml
```

It returned

> ConfigMap/aws-auth created

Then I understood that role ARN configured in `aws-auth-cm.yaml` is the wrong one. So I updated the same file with the exact worker node role ARN.

But this time I got 403 when I did `kubectl apply -f aws-auth-cm.yaml` again.

It returned

> Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current
>   configuration of: Resource: "/v1, Resource=configmaps",
>   GroupVersionKind: "/v1, Kind=ConfigMap" Name: "aws-auth", Namespace:
>   "kube-system" Object: &{map["apiVersion":"v1" "data":map["mapRoles":"-
>   rolearn: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/worker-node-role\n  username:
>   system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}\n  groups:\n    -
>   system:bootstrappers\n    - system:nodes\n"] "kind":"ConfigMap"
>   "metadata":map["name":"aws-auth" "namespace":"kube-system"
>   "annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""]]]}
>   from server for: "/home/username/aws-auth-cm.yaml": configmaps
>   "aws-auth" is forbidden: User
>   "system:node:ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX.ec2.internal" cannot get resource
>   "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system"

I'm not able to reconfigure the ConfigMap after this step.

I'm getting 403 for commands like

```
kubectl apply
kubectl delete
kubectl edit
```

for configmaps. Any help?

Comment: Have you exported the kubeconfig?

Comment: @Crou Yes I did.

Comment: Have you tried redoing the whole cluster from the scratch?

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason why `kubectl` returned 403 for this scenario.

As per this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html), the user/role who created the cluster will be given `system:masters` permissions in the cluster's `RBAC` configuration

When I tried to create a `ConfigMap` for `aws-auth` to join worker nodes, I gave the ARN of role/user who created the cluster instead of ARN of worker nodes.

And it updated the group(`system:masters`) of admin with groups `system:bootstrappers` and `system:nodes` in `RBAC` which basically locked the admin himself. And it is not recoverable since admin has lost the privileges from group `system:masters`.